# Sub-selects in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

### The Problem

I was recently completing a technical test, which required me to carry out a rather convoluted **SQL query**, and I'd like to know, ahead of any feedback I might receive, whether the answer I gave was correct, and how it might be improved.

Here's my *paraphrase* of the problem:

> Suppose we have a website selling *hats*, for which we want to build a database. Each type of hat has a size, price, etc. Each type of hat can also fall into none, one or more categories, and these categories can themselves be public or private.
>
> Do the following:
>
> 1. Write pseudo-SQL code creating the tables necessary to model the above.
> 2. Write a query which will return the records for types of hats which belong to **at least 5 public categories**.

### My Attempt

Since the bulk of my experience is with SQLite, I tackled this from an SQLite point of view, and I wrote this in a comment in my answer.

Regarding point (1) above, I created three tables: `Hat`, `Category` and `BelongsToCategory`, with the last being a join table for the first two. I made `public` a column of the `Category` table, of `INTEGER` type: 0 for false, 1 for true.

As for point (2), this is my query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Hat
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM BelongsToCategory
         JOIN Category ON Category.code = BelongsToCategory.category
         WHERE (BelongsToCategory.hat = Hat.code) AND (Category.public = 1))
    >= 5
```

### Testing My Attempt

I tested my attempt in the following fashion:

- I made my own .db file.
- I opened said file using the **Database Browser for SQLite**.
- I created my tables, as above.
- I added data to those tables, as follows:

  - I added three new records to the `Hat` table: hat1, hat2 and hat3.
  - I added six new records to the `Category` table: cat1 to cat6, where cat1 to cat5 were public, and cat6 was private.
  - I added records to the `BelongsToCategory` table, such that hat1 belonged to categories cat1 to cat5, hat2 belonged to cat1 only, and hat3 belonged to categories cat1 to cat4 and also to cat6.
- I ran the above SQL code.

When I ran the above SQL code, it returned the record for hat1. Job done! Not so fast... When I tried playing around with it a little, changing the 5 to a 4, or a 3, 2, etc, I kept getting the record for hat1, and nothing else. It was only when I got to 1 that hat3 started popping up, and I never saw hat2.

What's going here? **Is there something wrong with my query?** Or is this a bug in the SQLite browser?

### What I Want to Know

- Is the above SQL query correct?
- How might it be improved?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27

Comment: please add table structures along with sample data.

Comment: You approach seems reasonable, but the overall question seems too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is anything wrong with your query (I've tested it and it works as expected). As such I believe you might not be inserting the data as expected.

If you add the count sub query as an additional column to the main query and use >= 0 you can see the counts and see what is going on count wise

e.g. :-

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM BelongsToCategory
         JOIN Category ON Category.code = BelongsToCategory.category
         WHERE (BelongsToCategory.hat = Hat.code) AND (Category.public = true)) AS cat_count
FROM Hat
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM BelongsToCategory
         JOIN Category ON Category.code = BelongsToCategory.category
         WHERE (BelongsToCategory.hat = Hat.code) AND (Category.public = true))
    >= 0
;
```

The following was used to test the above :-

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BelongsToCategory;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Hat;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Category;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hat (code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hattype TEXT, hatprice REAL, hatsize REAL, hatetc TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category (code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, category TEXT, public INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BelongsToCategory (
    hat INTEGER REFERENCES Hat(code) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , category INTEGER REFERENCES Category(code) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , PRIMARY KEY(hat,category)
    )   
;

INSERT INTO Category VALUES(1,'cat1',true),(2,'cat2',true),(3,'cat3',true),(4,'cat4',true),(5,'cat5',true),(6,'cat6',false);
INSERT INTO Hat VALUES(1,'hat1',100,7,'other'),(2,'hat2',90,6,'other'),(3,'hat3',95,5,'other'),(4,'hat4',110,8,'other'),(5,'hat5',120,8,'other');
INSERT INTO BelongsToCategory VALUES
    (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6)
    ,(2,1)
    ,(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)
    ,(5,6),(5,1)
;

SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM BelongsToCategory
         JOIN Category ON Category.code = BelongsToCategory.category
         WHERE (BelongsToCategory.hat = Hat.code) AND (Category.public = true)) AS cat_count
FROM Hat
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM BelongsToCategory
         JOIN Category ON Category.code = BelongsToCategory.category
         WHERE (BelongsToCategory.hat = Hat.code) AND (Category.public = true))
    >= 0
;
```

The result of the above (using >=0) :-

[image]

(using >=5) :-

[image]

(using >=4) :-

[image]